# Using objects which must be aware of their container. Want to avoid annoying code repeats

Tags: c++

I have tree. It provides space partitioning services (not just BSP). Every node in tree may own (via unique_ptr) polymorphic object. These objects need to know to what node they were assigned. Thus, when creating object for node, I must pass node reference into constructor.

```
node.data.reset(new t_Something(node));
```

Typically I need to create (and assign to corresponding nodes) multiple objects, not just one.

```
node_a.data.reset(new t_Wing(node_a, /*wing args*/...));
node_h.data.reset(new t_Hall(node_h, /*hall args*/...));
node_b.data.reset(new t_Wing(node_b, /*wing args*/...));
```

I am developing content generators, in future I will write lots of code like this. I want to avoid repeating `node_XXX` in `node_XXX.data.reset(new T(node_XXXX`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a template:

```
#include <utility>    // for std::forward

template <typename T, typename N, typename ...Args>
N & add(N & node, Args &&... args)
{
    node.data.reset(new T(node, std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    return node;
}
```

Usage:

```
add<t_Wing>(node_a);                // appends new t_Wing(node_a)
add<x_Wing>(node_b, arg1, arg2);    // appends new x_Wing(node_b, arg1, arg2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have constructors that call `data.reset` themselves, you're already passing the node arguments.